# multivariate non-negative distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need a multivariate distribution defined over any vector (not special matrices as in case of Wishart distribution etc.) whose elements are non-negative (must include 0 as well). There is no other constraint over elements of the vector such as summing to 1; therefore, I can not use Dirichlet distribution.

Is there any such distribution? I could only think of using multinomial distribution or may be independent beta distributions.

Regards

Comment: What do you need it for?  Should the values be integers or real numbers? Could you take the squares or absolute values from a multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Comment: I need it to define a prior for the upper triangular part of a matrix that is non-negative. Integer or real numbers does not matter, I can reformulate accordingly. How can I use squares from multivariate Gaussian? I mean, how can I write pdf in such case?

Comment: It sounds as if you can use any positive random variable for each of the terms.

Comment: The square of a Gaussian random variable is a scaled chi-squared random variable with one degree of freedom (non-centred if the original Gaussian does not have mean $0$)

Comment: Related to the "using independent univariates", that's what I gonna do for now. But what if  want to define any correlation between terms? That's the reason I'm looking for multivariate distributions.